# Alternative LAG function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Maybe somebody could help me. I am using SQL Server 2005 and I can't use the `lag` function.

I have a table:

```
2014-02-03 07:42:00.000
2014-02-03 18:49:00.000
2014-02-06 14:54:00.000
2014-02-07 17:58:00.000
2014-02-20 13:39:00.000
```

How I can get this result:

```
2014-02-03 07:42:00.000 NULL
2014-02-03 18:49:00.000 2014-02-03 07:42:00.000 
2014-02-06 14:54:00.000 2014-02-03 18:49:00.000 
2014-02-07 17:58:00.000 2014-02-06 14:54:00.000 
2014-02-20 13:39:00.000 2014-02-07 17:58:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your table is called dt and the colum x then:

```
    select x,(select max(x) from dt d2 where d2.x<d1.x) from dt d1
```

Comment: is it not giving you the expected results or does it throw an error?

Comment: I have written the query for same case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244992/return-list-values-with-function

Answer (score 0):

this ill work even in SQL Server 7!

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f96a/10)

```
select min(date),null from datetable
union
select t1.date, max(t2.date)
from dateTable t1
join dateTable t2 on t2.date < t1.date
group by t1.date
```

Comment: I have written the new query for it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244992/return-list-values-with-function