# Return list values with function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write the query and is working fine with the one card_nr. Example:

```
Declare @card_nr as nvarchar(50)

set @card_nr = '704487442952000472'

select 
    a.times, b.times 
from 
    (select 
         stat_id, times 
     from info 
     where card_nr = @card_nr) as a 
left outer join 
    (select 
         stat_id, times 
     from info 
     where card_nr = @card_nr) as b on a.stat_id = b.stat_id+1
```

And I got the correct result:

```
2014-02-04 11:20:00.000 NULL
2014-02-06 09:44:00.000 2014-02-04 11:20:00.000
2014-02-12 09:59:00.000 2014-02-06 09:44:00.000
2014-02-13 10:31:00.000 2014-02-12 09:59:00.000
2014-02-21 09:49:00.000 2014-02-13 10:31:00.000
```

I want to do it for every `card_nr` from a table list. So, first I have written the function:

```
alter FUNCTION tabletest
   ( @card_nr as nvarchar(50))
RETURNS smalldatetime 
AS BEGIN
    Declare @sqldata as smalldatetime

    select 
        @sqldata = b.times 
    from 
        (select 
             stat_id, times 
         from info where card_nr = @card_nr) as a 
    left outer join 
        (select 
             stat_id, times 
         from info where card_nr = @card_nr ) as b on a.stat_id = b.stat_id + 1

   RETURN @datas 
END
```

After the function I have tried select my query:

```
select name, times, dbo.tabletest(card_nr)
from dbo.info
```

And I got incorrect result:

```
User1   2014-02-04 11:20:00.000 2014-02-21 09:49:00
User1   2014-02-06 09:44:00.000 2014-02-21 09:49:00
User1   2014-02-12 09:59:00.000 2014-02-21 09:49:00
User1   2014-02-13 10:31:00.000 2014-02-21 09:49:00
User1   2014-02-21 09:49:00.000 2014-02-21 09:49:00
User2   2014-02-14 13:41:00.000 2014-02-28 12:20:00
User2   2014-02-24 11:46:00.000 2014-02-28 12:20:00
User2   2014-02-28 12:20:00.000 2014-02-28 12:20:00
```

I would like to get this:

```
User1   2014-02-04 11:20:00.000 NULL
User1   2014-02-06 09:44:00.000 2014-02-04 11:20:00.000
User1   2014-02-13 10:31:00.000 2014-02-12 09:59:00.000
User1   2014-02-13 10:31:00.000 2014-02-12 09:59:00.000
User1   2014-02-21 09:49:00.000 2014-02-13 10:31:00.000
User2   2014-02-14 13:41:00.000 NULL
User2   2014-02-24 11:46:00.000 2014-02-14 13:41:00.000
User2   2014-02-28 12:20:00.000 2014-02-24 11:46:00.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be possible to get the desired result using table info only:

```
 select name, times, 
 (select max(times) from info i2 where i2.times<i1.times and i1.name=i2.name and i2.card_nr=@card_nr ) 
 from info i1
 where  card_nr=@card_nr
```

Comment: I will try it, but if i want to use the function. What would be the correct function and query?

Comment: I don't want to use a function they (the scalar one at least) can be slow sometimes. As a rule of thumb if you can do it with "plain" sql do it that way.

Comment: @jean agree, I would avoid function calls if possible

Comment: Why? I want use a function as the other way. Can you help? Yes, you query is working correct.

Comment: you can wrap this part inside the function:select max(times) from info i2 where i2.times<i1.times and i1.name=i2.name and i2.card_nr=@card_nr  and the use your original sql